# How should I proceed with bulk upload of files from frontend to cloud storage without uploading on server?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, digital-ocean-spaces

I have an RN mobile application, a ReactJs admin dashboard and backend nodejs server. Now I want to upload bulk files into my digitalocean spaces bucket without uploading them to the server. Also I don't want to directly upload to digitalocean's spaces as I have some processing of the data that needs to be done. I have searched and learned about "signed-urls", is there any better way to do this?